# Automate mysql 'limit' in php

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm working with a very large database and I'm not quite used to that yet. I need to cycle through 1,400 results (more being added regularly) and run functions based on each result IF criteria are met.

Here's the bones of my code:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
    WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
    AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
    AND spam = '0' 
    AND deleted = '0' 
    AND archived = '0' 
    order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
);
```

Then I run a foreach over them to get some data (blog name, specifically)

```
foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : 
    switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
    if(strpos(strtolower($blog_details->blogname), strtolower($_GET['squery'])) !== false){
    //Show the site's title and link to the site
}
```

endforeach;

Basically, in the first part, I'm grabbing all 1400 results, which doesn't do much buy give me the ID of all active blogs (that's about all there is in that database table).

In the second part, I run a wordpress function to grab the name of the blog and show it in a list ONLY IF the users query is in the blog's name. (I escape the input, no worries).

Someone said to use something like:

```
...
AND archived = '0'
LIMIT {$offset},20
order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
...
```

and that might work, but it only returns 20 results. If I need the end function to run on results #17 and #1,111, only #17 will show up?

so my **ultimate** question is:

Is there a way to get the "20 ~limit" part to cycle through ALL database entries? The memory usage without limiting it is ~200MB. If I could limit it to 20 at a time, but cycle through them all automatically, it (should??) cut down my memory usage a lot, right?

The end result now is:

- get 1400 results, run the function, show X blog names in a list.

What I'd LIKE (unless there's a better way in PHP-MySQL to cut memory expenses) is:

- get 20 results, run the function, show X blog names in a list. get 20
- more results (21-40), run the function, show X blog names in a list.
- get 20 more results (41-60), run the function, show X blog names in a
- list. etc...

all without more input from the user. Just to have them cycle automatically.

Comment: 1400 is not a big result, make sure your queries use the correct indexes and it will take less than a millisecond to pull the query and cycle the results..

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite figured what you want to do, but if you want to do something like showing list of blogs to user, but limit to 20 entries per request. You may use AJAX requests from client, like:

Client loads page with empty list -> XHR -> loads first 20 entries

Client scroll list -> XHR -> loads 20 entries more

**UPD:**

First, you must know max single entry size, e.g. if it's 1MB - you can load up to 200 entries per time (with your 200MB memory limit).
[Flushing](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) data to client is not nessesary, but if you page will generates for long a while it will send data to client per parts.

Something like this:

```
$i=0;
while(!$end){
  $q = query('
  ...
  AND archived = '0'
  LIMIT {$i*200},{$i*200+200}
  order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
  ...
  ');
  echo fetch_my_query($q); //fetch and echo data
  $i++;
  if(mysql_num_rows($q) != 200)$end = True; //Got all entries in DB
  flush();
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I want to do. 

When a user types in "Salem" I need to show all results that have Salem in the blog name. I want to limit my query to 20 results at a time, and then fetch the next 20 and see if it's there, and then the next 20, and so on and so-forth. I think it would cut down on memory usage, which is my main concern. The user would type in "salem" and still get a list of ALL the results, but the mysql query would only store 20 in memory at a time. Something like that,

Comment: Hm, it's freaky, but you can use output buffer. Fetch 20 entries > flush to client > clean memory -> Fetch next... But remember that so many requests to DB server will cause high load

Comment: you will have to use the answer proposed or implement simple pagination also with OFFSET and LIMIT

Comment: @Aphex - can you show me an example using that? I can't seem to find any documention on how to flush it to the client clean the memory and then continue. I'm not worried about the amount of queries, It's never used by many people at once, but I certainly can't have it using 200MB (soon more) of memory per person.

I'm eventually going to probably have to create a new table every week with new entries and fetch from that, but I need a solution like I've mentioned as more of an immediate fix, haha

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply change the query and add an extra WHERE in it with the limit ?

For example, if I understand correctly your code:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
    WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
    AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
    AND spam = '0' 
    AND deleted = '0' 
    AND archived = '0' 
    AND `field containing the blog name` LIKE '%".$_GET['squery']."%'
    LIMIT 20  #you can add the offset if you paginate the results
    order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
);
```

you might have to do a JOIN to a different table to grab the blogname.

Not knowing your DB structure I can only attempt a query:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT b.blog_id,b.path
    FROM {$wpdb->blogs} `b`
       LEFT JOIN table_with_blog_name db ON db.id = b.blog_id
    WHERE b.blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
       AND b.site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
       AND b.spam = '0' 
       AND b.deleted = '0' 
       AND b.archived = '0' 
       AND db.field_with_blog_name LIKE '%".$_GET['squery']."%'
    LIMIT 20  #you can add the offset if you paginate the results
    ORDER BY b.blog_id", ARRAY_A
);
```

Don't forget to sanitize the `$_GET['squery']` first